# Authenticate on premise (integrated windows authentication) application with Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Our client uses azure where in our their active directory is synced with azure ad and configured pass-through authentication.

Now we need to configure on premise applications (which are configured with Integrated windows authentication) to authenticate with azure ad without any changes to our application. Is it possible?  I have looked at the Application proxy but it talks more on enabling remote access to the application. we don't want to expose application outside the network.

Comment: What exactly is it you want to do? You want to migrate these apps to AAD auth so you can get rid of on-prem AD?

Comment: yes need to authenticate on premise apps to AAD

Answer (score 0):

Your application currently utilizes Integrated Windows Authentication against an on-prem AD.

Azure AD does not support this method of authentication.

So if you wish to remove the on-prem AD dependency for auth, you will have to modify the app to do authentication with OpenId Connect / WS-Federation / SAML2.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is enabling SSO on azure ad.

If SSO is enabled and you are logged in to windows.
,  Logon screen from azure is not shown.

For other users logon screen is shown where they can enter the credentials.  Please note that other users have to click on cancel before the authentication logic throws login error.

Please read IWA SSO from below link.

Documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-single-sign-on